# How to add layer to OpenLayers, but without it getting automatically added in LayerSwitcher Control?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a OpenLayers web map with LayerSwitcher control added. I need this to switch some of my layers. But I am also adding and removing some layers, which are temporary and I do not want them added to the LayerSwitcher Control.

So is there a way to add layer to OpenLayers, but without it getting automatically added in LayerSwitcher Control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple, just set `displayInLayerSwitcher: false` in the layer options.